# Scrollbar on "fullpage js"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating my web-page by using `fullpageJs` https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ plugin, and trying to make accordion FAQ page.

Basically the accordion refers to https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/QXdqR

The problem is when accordion exceeds the page height, the scrollbar doesn't work properly. (I'm activating "scrollOverflow" option)

Here is my current jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
　$('.accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function() {
　　$(this).next().slideToggle('600');
　$(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('600');
　});
$('.accordion-toggle').on('click', function() {
　$.fn.fullpage.reBuild();
　$(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
　});
});
```

I just added `$.fn.fullpage.reBuild();`, trying to solve the problem.

However, I'm still stucking with three problems below;

1. It works only when the scrollbar is originally shown in the screen. (When "Q" content exceeds the height of screen)
2. Whole accordion move to unpredicted position after opening & closing answer. 
   (This happens when scrollbar originally isn’t displayed on the screen and then exceeds the height when the accordion opens. (This is hard to explain in words, and I hope the explanation makes sense…))
3. It seems adding `$.fn.fullpage.reBuild();` makes the page slow to load. (especially on mobile). Is there any way to solve this?

*By the way, I could get an ideal result when I resized browser each time after opening & closing answers.*

...That’s it. 
I would appreciate it very much if someone taught me any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    scrollOverflow: true
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I've already activated "scrollOverflow". The problem is all about the scrollbar that is shown by setting ’scrollOverflow: true’.